# Horizontal scrolling table - disappearing padding on right edge

Tags: css, html-table

I want to use a container to wrap a table so that it can scroll horizontally on mobile screens:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 0px;
 }
.table-wrapper {
 width: calc(100% + 20px);
 overflow: auto;
 margin-left: -10px;
 margin-right: -10px;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
table caption {
   text-align: left;
   padding: 5px 5px;
   background: black;
   color: white;
}
table { /* for illustration purposes */
  width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <caption>title of the table</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Away</td>
        <td>Pts</td>
        <td>Home</td>
        <td>Pts</td>
        <td>Match</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

To make it clear that the table scrolls horizontally, I've used negative margins on the sides of the `.table-wrapper` so that the table butts up against the right edge of the screen (run the code snippet to see it in action). Then I've padded the sides of the `.table-wrapper` so that there's a comfortable space again when you've scrolled all the way to the left or right edge of the table.

However, while this padding manifests as desired on the left edge, it doesn't show up on the right edge (because the `.table-wrapper` is only 100% of the screen width). This seems to be the case across browsers.

Is there a CSS-only fix so that a padding appears on the right edge of the table *only* when you scroll all the way to the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.table-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
table {
  display: inline-table; /*key*/
  width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table caption {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <caption>title of the table</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Away</td>
        <td>Pts</td>
        <td>Home</td>
        <td>Pts</td>
        <td>Match</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, `inline-table`! This is literally the first time I've seen it used in practice. Now I know what it's good for.

Comment: Well, you can also use it for displaying a table side by side with other inline level elements.